# Using Raspberry Pi as Wifi AP : WPA[2]-PSK works but EAP-TLS results in "IE in 3/4 msg does not match with IE in Beacon/ProbeResp"

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, hostapd, wpa2

For some testing, I'm trying to set up a WPA2-Enterprise network with EAP-TLS, and connect to it from an Android phone. I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4B running Raspbian to host the network, with its in-built wireless adapter. I'm using `hostapd` to set up the wireless network, and using its integrated EAP server (rather than a separate RADIUS server). Here is my `hostapd.conf`:

```
country_code=GB
interface=wlan0
ssid=Pi
hw_mode=g
channel=7
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2 # WPA2 only
ieee8021x=1
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wme_enabled=1
ieee80211w=0
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd

eap_server=1 # Use integrated EAP server instead of external
eap_user_file=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.eap_user

ca_cert=/etc/hostapd/keys/ca-cert-selfsigned.pem
server_cert=/etc/hostapd/keys/server-cert-signed-by-ca.pem
private_key=/etc/hostapd/keys/server-unencrypted-private-key.pem


# Logging:
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=0
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=0
```

Here is my `hostapd.eap_user`:

```
"alice" TLS
```

My certificates are set up as follows: I generated three keypairs, for the CA, server, and a single client respectively. They are all signed by the CA (so the CA cert is self-signed). The CA cert is installed as a trusted root cert on the Raspberry Pi. On the Android device while setting up the wifi network, I give it the CA certificate and the client's private key and certificate.

When I try to connect to it from an Android device, it fails. Here are the `wpa_supplicant` logs I see on Android:

```
wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'Pi'
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=00
wlan0: Associated with <REDACTED MAC ADDRESS>
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=13
TLS - SSL error: error:0900006e:PEM routines:OPENSSL_internal:NO_START_LINE
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 13 (TLS) selected
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=1 subject='/CN=PiNetworkRoot' hash=1406e3c8badbc11b69936fee60ef3ee138cd08ce5c4fcfc0a0a23e4aba89bb50
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=0 subject='/CN=PiNetworkServer' hash=d62843124235b66100f4c23de52eb4eed76224b094c7917c1be3b5082b6e7a74
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
wlan0: PMKSA-CACHE-ADDED <REDACTED MAC ADDRESS> 0
wlan0: WPA: IE in 3/4 msg does not match with IE in Beacon/ProbeResp (src=<REDACTED MAC ADDRESS>)
WPA: RSN IE in Beacon/ProbeResp - hexdump(len=22): 30 14 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 01 0d 00
WPA: RSN IE in 3/4 msg - hexdump(len=22): 30 14 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 01 0c 00
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=<REDACTED MAC ADDRESS> reason=17 locally_generated=1
```

So it looks like the EAP authentication completed successfully, but then there was some other problem. Here are the `hostapd` logs for the same:

```
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.11: associated
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> WPA: event 1 notification
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.1X: start authentication
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> WPA: start authentication
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.1X: unauthorizing port
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.1X: Sending EAP Packet (identifier 81)
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.1X: received EAP packet (code=2 id=81 len=10) from STA: EAP Response-Identity (1)
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.1X: Sending EAP Packet (identifier 82)
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.1X: received EAP packet (code=2 id=82 len=145) from STA: EAP Response-TLS (13)
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.1X: Sending EAP Packet (identifier 83)
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.1X: received EAP packet (code=2 id=83 len=6) from STA: EAP Response-TLS (13)
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.1X: Sending EAP Packet (identifier 84)
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.1X: received EAP packet (code=2 id=84 len=1408) from STA: EAP Response-TLS (13)
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.1X: Sending EAP Packet (identifier 85)
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.1X: received EAP packet (code=2 id=85 len=473) from STA: EAP Response-TLS (13)
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.1X: Sending EAP Packet (identifier 86)
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.1X: received EAP packet (code=2 id=86 len=6) from STA: EAP Response-TLS (13)
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.1X: Sending EAP Packet (identifier 86)
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> WPA: sending 1/4 msg of 4-Way Handshake
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> WPA: received EAPOL-Key frame (2/4 Pairwise)
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> WPA: sending 3/4 msg of 4-Way Handshake
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> IEEE 802.11: disassociated
wlan0: STA <MAC ADDRESS REDACTED> WPA: event 2 notification
```

I tried Googling "IE in 3/4 msg does not match with IE in Beacon/ProbeResp" and found several results, some quite old. Some mentioned `wme_enabled=0`, so I tried that, but it was still the same issue. [This](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191061&start=75) talked about PMF on a related but different problem, [from which I got to](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf) `ieee80211w=1`. I tried that too (all 4 combinations of having/not having `ieee80211w=1` and `wme_enabled=0`). But it's the same error in all cases. Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Changing `wpa=2` to `wpa=1` made the connection succeed, which suffices for my testing purposes, though potentially not for real use depending on requirements.**

[This bug](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/3619) might be relevant.

---

The wifi network works if I use PSK instead of EAP-TLS, as with the following `hostapd.conf`:

```
country_code=GB
interface=wlan0
ssid=Pi_PSK
hw_mode=g
channel=7
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=Foobar
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

I can connect to this network successfully from the same Android device.

Comment: Remove the `wpa-pairwise` statement, and remove `TKIP` from the `rsn-pairwise` statement. WME should be enabled, and 11w should be disabled (for now).

Comment: @Spiff Thanks - I did that (and restarted hostapd), it's the same error though. The hexdump of the RSN IE changed slightly.

Comment: @Ramhound There's no Windows here. The wifi host/server is running Raspbian and the client is running Android 8.0.

Comment: Setting `wpa=1` made the connection work, which suffices for my testing purposes.

Comment: Same hostapd on Raspberry Pi 3B+ with broadcom 4329 wlan chipset. It works fine with WPA-PSK. It fails at very end of pairing with WPA2 enterprise from linux station while WPA2 enterprise works with windows 10 Home with very same hardware old dell laptop D630. Fixed with rsn_preauth=1 in hosapd.conf.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem on Pi4/ModelB with Pi OS.
The difference of RSN IE is only bit 0 (Pre-Auth capability).
So I added following:

```
rsn_preauth=1
rsn_preauth_interface=eth0
```

This works fine.
I will try USB WiFi adapter for investigating driver's bug or not.

Comment: Realtek RTL8188CU wifi adapter works fine without `rsn_preauth`.

Comment: This one took me a long time to fix, same connection from the very same computer was working from windows 10 home and failing from ubuntu 20 & 22.=; adding rsn_preauth=1 in hostapd config did fix it. hostapd is on Pi3 Model B+ .